# How do you use pollUntil with intern 4 functional tests

Tags: intern, leadfoot

I'm writing intern 4 functional tests. When I try to use pollUntil it is undefined

```
  .findDisplayedByCssSelector('button.primary')
  .then( el => pollUntil(function(pollEl) {
      if( pollEl.isEnabled() ) return true;
      return null;
  }, el, 300000 )
```

Error:

```
 chrome 63.0.3239.132 on Windows NT -  Test - do create (0.352s)
   ReferenceError: pollUntil is not defined
     at Command.remote.findDisplayedByClassName.findByXpath.click.clearValue.type.end.end.findDisplayedByCssSelector.then.end.findDisplayed
```

I've tried various things to import the pollUntil function like

```
const { pollUntil } = require('leadfoot/helpers/pollUntil');
```

None have worked.

Anyone have a hint on how to access pollUntil?

Answer (score 0):

`pollUntil` is the default export of the `helpers/pollUntil` module. Intern and Leadfoot are built using ESM default export semantics, so the default export is called "default". Try:

```
const { default: pollUntil } = require('leadfoot/helpers/pollUntil');
```

or

```
const pollUntil = require('leadfoot/helpers/pollUntil').default;
```